Passing custom command line arguments to Neovim?
I would like to write something like nvim --custom-argument 29 to launch Neovim from the command line, and use arguments in my init.lua to trigger code depending on if it exists or what its value is.

Have you considered using environment variables or a wrapper script instead?

I can use --cmd to run commands before configs are loaded, and do nvim --cmd "let g:value=v:true" to add a variable set to true for instance.

That is way better :-) I didn't knew for --cmd (or I forgot ;-) ).

There are two difficulties with your demand:

Vim accepts only some predefined flags and complains if you provide unsupported ones
The Vim flags have a meaning and will be interpreted by Vim changing Vim behavior (what you don't want).

To dodge these two problems I propose to:

Use the -c flag of Vim that let you pass a Vim a statement to be executed after Vim initialization (way after init.lua is executed). This addresses 1.
Use a comment statement as an argument of the the -c flag (string starting with "). This addresses 2 since executing a comment statement means doing nothing.

The idea of the following piece of code is to execute the comments statements that starts with : at init.lua execution (the non comment statement will continue to be executed after Vim initialization).
You could do on Windows:
nvim -c """:let g:custom_argument=29"

Remark: This is command argument passing for Windows (the second argument will be ":let g:custom_argument=29)
Or if you are using the Qt flavor:
nvim-qt -- -c "\"!let g:custom_argument=29"

Or on Linux:
nvim -c "\"!let g:custom_argument=29"

Remark: This is command argument passing for Linux (the second argument will be ":let g:custom_argument=29)
In the init.lua you could parse the command line argument using the vim.v.argv variable.
e.g.:
for k, v in pairs(vim.v.argv) do
  if v == "-c" then
    if string.sub(vim.v.argv[k + 1], 0, 2) == '":' then
      -- Executes the comment statements that starts with ':'
      vim.cmd(string.sub(vim.v.argv[k + 1], 2))
    end
  end
end
print(vim.g.custom_argument)


It might be a good idea to explain why you pass a comment to -c; it took me a moment to understand the strategy of smuggling custom arguments in via comments.

Thanks @D.BenKnoble, I have elaborated a bit more the idea behind the solution.
